# Getting character "N" and "\r" in bytes. Weird? Isn't it?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, byte

I am sending data to a device through TCP socket connection. Device only responds back when sent data is correct. I'm receiving data using the below line of code.

```
a = s.recv(8)
print(a) 
#b'\xfe\xfe\xef\x00N\xaa\xfe\r'
a[6:8] == b'\xfe\x0D'
#true
```

Why am i getting true for last condition? I know last two bytes of data coming from device is "FE0D". So why python is showing "\r" in place of b'/x0D'.

Answer (score 1):

> So why python is showing "\r" in place of b'/x0D'.

Because `\r` is the same as `\x0D`. `\r` is [Carriage Return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) with has the [ASCII code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Control_characters) 13 or `0D` in hexadecimal. Similar `N` has the ASCII code 78 which is the same as `\x4E`.

Comment: yeah, got it. Thanks. But can i prevent it from being read like "b'\xfe\xfe\xef\x00N\xaa\xfe\r'". Instead I want it like "b'\xfe\xfe\xef\x00\x4e\xaa\xfe\x0D'.

Comment: @Coder: I don't think that you can change the default printing of bytes used by `print`. But you can do `print(''.join('\\x%02x' % i for i in a))`